# Symmetry problem involving functions

Tags: symmetry

I was given a definition.

> A symmetry of a plane figure $F$ is an isometry that maps $F$ to itself, that is, an isometry $f:R^2 \to R^2$ such that $f(F)=F$.

I don't really understand this because is $F$ not a collection of points and the domain of the function consists of single points in $R^2$?

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: [$\color{white}{related}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3833732/721644)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $F$ is a subset of $R^2$.

$f(F)$ is shorthand for the set $\{f(x) : x \in F\}$. The statement "$f(F) = F$" is a set equality.

Comment: Is that something you cn do with functions? if you are not considering just a single point you can input a set of points and it will give the image set of all them point?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes we want to look at the range of a set $S$ and denote this set as $f(S).$